# PInvokeStackImbalance was detected in my program

Tags: vb.net

I try to get coordinates where left mouse clicked during timer is working.
But I had a error as "PInvokeStackImbalance was detected" .
How do you get rid of this error?
The partial program is following.

enter code here

```
Private Declare Function GetAsyncKeyState Lib "user32" (ByVal vkey As Long) As Integer
Declare Sub mouse_event Lib "user32" Alias "mouse_event" (ByVal dwFlags As Integer, ByVal dx As Integer, ByVal dy As Integer, ByVal cButtons As Integer, ByVal dwExtraInfo As Integer)
Public Const MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = &H2
Public Const MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = &H4
Public Const MOUSEEVENTF_MIDDLEDOWN = &H20
Public Const MOUSEEVENTF_MIDDLEUP = &H40
Public Const MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN = &H8
Public Const MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP = &H10
Dim Mouse_LeftClick As Boolean

Private Sub TimerRec_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TimerRec.Tick

    Mouse_LeftClick = GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.LButton) ' **error occured here!**
    If Mouse_LeftClick Then
        Messagebox.show(MousePosition.X.ToString & " " & MousePosition.Y.ToString)
    End If



End Sub
```

Comment: Your PInvoke signature looks significantly different to the one shown on [PInvoke.Net](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.getasynckeystate), and looking at the [Microsoft Docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646293(v=vs.85).aspx) I think I agree with theirs. Where/how did you come up with that signature?

Comment: I found this code in my friends code.
I actually don't understand about PInvoke.

Comment: The `mouse_event` declaration is also incorrect. Both are for VB6. Use the **VB.NET** declaration from the link Damien gave you, and also from this: http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.mouse_event